# Issue with Log Transform of Dependent Variable

Tags: r, modeling, data-transformation

I am trying to predict a financial variable that is highly skewed. I thought I should log transform it, but that is causing difficulties, as I am also concerned with accurately modeling the overall mean of the data. When I exponentiate the predictions, and take the mean, I underestimate significantly the true mean. I am pretty sure this is because if the data (y) is skewed toward the right, then mean(y) > mean(exp(log(y))).

I am not sure if this is an issue only with linear models. I am also not sure how to go about fixing it. Below is some code illustrating the problem (modeling code is from tidymodels book), just for illustration:

```
library(tidymodels)
data(ames)
ames <- mutate(ames, Sale_Price = log(Sale_Price))

ames_rec <- 
  recipe(Sale_Price ~ Neighborhood + Gr_Liv_Area + Year_Built + Bldg_Type + 
           Latitude + Longitude, data = ames) %>%
  step_log(Gr_Liv_Area, base = 10) %>% 
  step_other(Neighborhood, threshold = 0.01) %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>% 
  step_interact( ~ Gr_Liv_Area:starts_with("Bldg_Type_") ) %>% 
  step_ns(Latitude, Longitude, deg_free = 20)

lm_model <- linear_reg() %>% set_engine("lm")

lm_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(lm_model) %>% 
  add_recipe(ames_rec)

lm_fit <- fit(lm_wflow, ames)
predictions <- predict(lm_fit, new_data = ames %>% select(-Sale_Price))

bind_cols(ames %>% select(Sale_Price), predictions) %>% 
  mutate(Sale_Price_Orig = exp(Sale_Price), Predicted = exp(.pred)) %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), mean))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Sale_Price .pred Sale_Price_Orig Predicted
       <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>     <dbl>
1       12.0  12.0         180796.   178206.
```

In this example, the true mean is $2,590 or 1.5% higher than the predicted mean. In my world, this would be bad!

One possibility is to use the 180996 / 178206 ratio as a multiplicative factor across all predictions, but I am not convinced that is a good idea.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

David

Comment: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smearing_retransformation

Comment: See [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=duan%20smear*) for threads related to @NickCox's suggestion.

Comment: @whuber recommendation is very helpful. The formula wikipedia article is confusing, as it  refers to sigma^2, which is the rmse of the model not the variance of the estimates. Also the wikipedia article is showing the normal assumption variant, as opposed to the more general average of the transformed residuals as the adjustment factor.